# How to fix gitLab pipeline failure

Tags: gitlab, hugo

so I have been trying to push some commits to the GitLab origin, but for some reason, the pipeline is keep failing. Here is the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fasG.jpg)

I created a different branch named scrolling-logo and tried to merge it with the master branch on GitLab using git push origin, but somehow the pipeline is keep showing errors.

I tried git pull to update the master branch to its latest version on my local machine and then again tried to push to the GitLab, but it is still not working.

Does anyone know why this problem occurs?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a [similar issue](https://github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-themes/issues/1665), make sure your GitLab pipeline does install and use the `hugo_extended` image, as in [`pages/hugo` `.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/pages/hugo/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml).

```yaml
image: registry.gitlab.com/pages/hugo/hugo_extended:latest

# Set this if you intend to use Git submodules
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  HUGO_ENV: production

default:
  before_script:
    - apk add --update --no-cache git go
    - git submodule update --init --recursive
    - hugo mod init gitlab.com/pages/hugo
    - hugo mod get -u github.com/theNewDynamic/gohugo-theme-ananke

test:
  script:
    - hugo
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

pages:
  script:
    - hugo
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

That could be enough to avoid this error.

---

The [OP Chin-Erdene Gantulga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19564415/chin-erdene-gantulga) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74974614/how-to-fix-gitlab-pipeline-failure/74979287?noredirect=1#comment132377549_74979287):

> There was this image conflict within the docker so I changed manually the image in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` from "`latest`" version to "`hugo:0.91.0`".
> Then it worked.

Comment: @Chin-ErdeneGantulga Great, well done! Did you made any adjustments compared to the workflow I proposed above?

Comment: There was this image conflict within the docker so I changed manually the image in the .gitlab-ci.yml from "latest version to hugo:0.91.0". Then it worked!